# ActiveAndroid - How to drop and recreate/truncate tables on DB version update?

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, activeandroid

Is it a way we can **skip/prevent** certain migration scripts from running?
or use **onUpgrade in activeandroid**

Consider the following scenario,

1.0 version of App deployed to play store with DB version 1 and TABLE 1 with 1 column.

2.0 version of App deployed to play store with DB version 2 and TABLE 1 with 3 column now.

Is there a way where we can use onUpgrade in activeandroid or skip Migration script part?

I came through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495753/activeandroid-how-to-drop-and-recreate-all-tables-on-db-version-update) but migration script part was not clear to me, even [this documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Schema-migrations) gives nothing to create migration script.

Comment: About your scenario, does it mean that you want to add two more columns into TABLE 1 on version 2?

Comment: Yes, but this not just the case.I might need to alter some or few tables according to need. I did some more digging and understood how to use migration script, but if that is the case there is no point in using the ActiveAndroid library because you are eventually writing raw SQL queries to migration file.

Comment: You're right. ActiveAndroid helps us to map an Object to SQLite table only. If you want to add more columns into a table or upgrade table records, you need to write raw SQL queries.

Comment: adding to that, even if I decided to use this library and write migration script, it wont let me create getters & setters for newly added columns in that table.

Comment: Why? Newly added columns are totally the same to existed columns. You can add getters and setters as usual.